# Flawed reasoning in proving $A\subseteq B$ iff $A-B=\emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Prove $A\subseteq B$ iff $A-B=\emptyset$.

Assume $A\subseteq B$. This means that if $a\in A$ then $a\in B$. Since $A-B$ means all $a\in A$ such that $a\not\in B$, we can see that $A-B=\emptyset$.

Now assume $A-B=\emptyset$. This means that there are no $a\in A$ such that $a\not\in B$. This implies that if $a\in A$ then $a\in B$. Therefore $A\subseteq B$.

Since we have shown that $(A\subseteq B)\Rightarrow (A-B=\emptyset )\wedge (A-B=\emptyset )\Rightarrow (A\subseteq B)$, we can conclude that $A\subseteq B$ iff $A-B=\emptyset$.

$\blacksquare$

Though I can't pinpoint anywhere I went wrong here, I can't help but feel there's a hole in my reasoning somewhere... is this a valid proof?

Comment: This seems fairly straightforward. I see no flaws.

Comment: Why does it feel off?  That reasoning seems sound.  $A\subset B$ means every element of $A$ is an element of $B$.  And that means there is no element of $A$ not in $B$.  So $A-B$ = all the elements of A not in B, is empty.  And the implications are reversable.  Your argument follows that nicely.

Comment: Fair enough! I'm quite new to more advanced math and I'm self teaching so I don't get much feedback. I guess I'm sometimes thrown off by arguments that seem overly simple or trivial. This one didn't concrete enough for some reason. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Your proof looks correct, or you can write:

\begin{align}
&A\subseteq B\leftrightarrow A- B=\varnothing\\
\equiv&~\forall_x ((x\in A\to x\in B)\leftrightarrow \neg(x\in A\land x\not\in B))\\
\equiv&~\forall_x ((x\in A\to x\in B)\leftrightarrow (x\in A\to x\in B))\\
\equiv&~\top
\end{align}